# Regex in python to catch a string like MMS-2839

Tags: python, regex

How can I catch some string like these with a regex in python?

```
M1Sxs-2839
McS-28S9213
```

Both the first and the second part (divided by the -) can contains letters and numbers (case insensitive).

Comment: what is exactly what you want to accomplish? if you want "any number of letters and numbers followed by a hyphen followed by any number of letters and numbers" and nothing else, you can use @Avinash's answer. It does let you do stuff like 0-1 or x-x though... if you don't want to allow that, you should be more explicit... do they have a minimum? do they have to start with an M? or any letter? should that be only uppercase? your question, as it is, it's too broad... the following code detects both of them `re.match(".*")`. You need to narrow down what you mean by "some string like these"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below `re.match` function.

```
re.match(r"(?i)[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+$", st)
```

`(?i)` helps to do case-insensitive match. Since `re.match` scans the input from start, you don't need to add start of the line anchor `^` explicitly.